# How to reindex solr after deleting a row from PostgreSql?

Tags: indexing, solr

I am taking a csv dump from my database and indexing the table using solr.If I delete a row from the table, how to remove that row from Solr index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several strategies:

1. Know what your deleted IDs are by marking them deleted in the original database and sending special [$deleteDocById](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-SpecialCommandsfortheDataImportHandler) key in DataImportHandler
2. Periodically delete everything and reindex from scratch, that way the legacy records go away
3. Automatically add a field with "date-indexed" for every record (e.g. in the UpdateRequestProcessor chain) and then, at the end of the reindexing, run a query to delete any records that have an old "date-indexed" as it indicates it has not been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You must have added a unique key to solr.

Check your solr.xml for the same.

Get that id of the row and fire the query to solr

mention the id in the query as 111111 is been mentioned.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=
<delete><query>id:111111</query></delete>&commit=true
```

If you want to delete all items in the index, just use this query:

```
<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

for more info please go through

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages

when you delete entries from your Postgre database. Either keep a flag or make an entry of the same deleted ids in another table named X. Later on run a scheduler for solr cleaning up the deleted entries from Solr. Run the delete query on solr by passing those ids from tabel X to it and remove the entries from solr.

Comment: I am asking that if someone deletes 5-6 rows from the database, how would we know that what are the ids for which rows are deleted and delete them from solr

Comment: Actually say for example, I indexed 10 rows from a database.Someone deleted 2 rows from the database.When I reindex Solr,it will update 8 rows but it won't affect the 2 rows which were deleted in the database.How to find those rows which were deleted and remove them from solr index

Comment: when you delete those entries from your table successfully then after that  give the call to solr with those unique id mentioning in the solr query to delete the entry from the solr index.

Comment: when you delete those entries from your Postgre database. Either keep a flag or make an entry of the same in another table. Later on run a scheduler for solr cleaning up the deleted entries from your database. run the delete query on solr by passing those ids to it and remove the entries from solr.

Comment: I have also implemented the same in my application. I delete the entry from solr index when I delete the entry in my application database. It makes sure for me that deleted entried in my database gets deleted from solr as well

Comment: did you got the idea?